# Noise equivalent power of thermopile sensor?

Tags: noise, thermocouple, signal-to-noise, noise-spectral-density

I am working on the characterisation of thermopile sensor and stuck in determining the NEP of the sensor.
My thermopile sensor with AD8630 amplifier receives IR radiation coming from the blackbody at 500K. To calculate noise equivalent power I have calculated output voltage of the thermopile by simply taking the output of the sensor and power incident through power meter but I am not sure how to calculate the noise voltage ? should I take Johnson noise as the noise voltage ? if so then how can I calculate it ?
Please, someone give me an idea about how to deal with NEP in such situation.

Thank you and stay safe

Comment: What thermopile sensor? Does it have a part number?

Comment: Its a random thermopile for conducting characterisation. Do i need just the johnson noise for NEP or do i have to place the noise of the whole system ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually Johnson-Nyquist noise is dominant in thermopile detectors.

So NEP =  Vn/Rv where Vn is the J-N noise voltage per root-Hz and Rv is the responsivity of the detector in volts/watt, giving the result in W/root-Hz. That’s for the sensor alone, the amplifier noise will add to it (typically it’s uncorrelated noise so it adds in quadrature).

Johnson-Nyquist noise follows the formula Vn = \$\sqrt{4k_BTRB}\$ where kB is Boltzman’s constant, T is the temperature in Kelvin, R is the electrical resistance and B is the bandwidth - calculated per sqrt 1 Hz in this case.

You might want to check out some of the publications of the esteemed British scientist R.V. Jones, who did a lot of the pioneering work in this field, in support of the war effort in WWII.

Comment: I know that J-N noise is atleast 5 times greater than the environmental noise but I am not sure how can i calculate Johnson noise voltage per root-Hz of the thermopile ? How would i separate this johnson noise from the environmental noise and the noise of the amplifier ?